# Starting Wicket web application with OSGi HTTP Service

Tags: osgi, wicket, embedded-jetty, apache-felix, httpservice

I'm trying to start a Wicket Application using Felix implementation of OSGi HTTP service, for that I just register the service using `WicketServlet` with `applicationClassName` parameter:

```
props.put("applicationClassName", MainApplication.class.getName());
service = (HttpService)context.getService(httpReference);
service.registerServlet("/", new WicketServlet(), props, null);
```

I have also tried using Felix Whiteboard implementation and registering the web service as a `Servlet` one:

```
props.put("alias", "/");
props.put("init.applicationClassName", MainApplication.class.getName());
registration = context.registerService(Servlet.class.getName(), new WicketServlet(), props);
```

In both cases it fails when I deploy it using Pax Runner and Felix (`mvn package install pax:run -Dframework=felix -Dprofiles=log,config`), the exception seems to be related with the `ClassLoader`:

```
[Jetty HTTP Service] ERROR org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard - Failed to register servlet
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Unable to create application of class es.warp.sample.HTTPLocalGUI.MainApplication
....
....
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
....
....
```

I have tried to export everything in the bundle and it does the same.

The strangest thing is that it works perfectly if I deploy it using Equinox (`mvn package install pax:run -Dframework=felix -Dprofiles=log,config`).

It seems to be a visibilty issue, but I don't know how to fix it, am I doing something wrong? Should I try to extend `WicketServlet` to take control on the instantiation of the application? Or maybe using an application Factory?

**Update: Or maybe using an application Factory?**

I tried to set the parameter `applicationFactoryClassName` to `ContextParamWebApplicationFactory.class.getName()` it and didn't help, still failing with felix and working with equinox.

Any light is welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that Wicket seems to load the *applicationClass* badly. I have not looked at the code that does this, but I suspect it's using current thread's context classloader.

I did the following to overcome this:

1. Create my own `WicketFilter` (called `MyWicketFilter`) and override `getClassLoader`. This returns `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`.
2. Register the `MyWicketFilter` as a Filter service to be picked up by the whiteboard http service.

Code for activator start:

```
Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
props.put("pattern", "/.*");
props.put("init.applicationClassName", MyApplication.class.getName());

final MyWicketFilter service = new MyWicketFilter();
context.registerService(Filter.class.getName(), service, props);
```

Code for MyWicketFilter:

```
public final class MyWicketFilter
    extends WicketFilter
{
    @Override
    protected ClassLoader getClassLoader()
    {
        return this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    }
}
```

You can also use `WicketServlet`, but this involves overriding
`newWicketFilter` and return MyWicketFilter from here.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't seem to work for me? Instead of the code in activator start I set it in my web.xml file:

     <filter>
  <filter-name>wicket.web-hub</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.hub.web.base.MyWicketFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
   <param-value>com.hub.web.base.WicketApplication</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>