# Static content on Wicket application served from OSGi HTTP Service

Tags: css, osgi, wicket, httpservice, static-content

I'm developing a web application that is going to be served from an OSGi HTTP service, [I register it using a WicketServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432263/starting-wicket-web-application-with-osgi-http-service), and I don't know how to serve static files (CSS, JS, images and so).

How could I mount a directory as a resource with the static content?

Or should I configure the resource locator in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in top-level directory are served by default.