# Wicket feature unable to find its classes during deployment of wicket application in ServiceMix

Tags: deployment, wicket, osgi-bundle, wicket-1.5, apache-servicemix

After I install Apache Wicket feature in my servicemix(instalation goes without any problems) during deployment of my application I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.request.Request not found by org.apache.wicket.core [180]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_101]`

When I include **the same wicket jars that I use while installing them to SMX** in my WAR during deployment and add them to classpath in my applications' manifest there is no issue.

Here's definition of my wicket feature in features.xml

```
<feature name="wicket-spring" version="1.5.16" description="Wicket spring" resolver="(obr)">
    <feature version="1.5.16">wicket-ioc</feature>
    <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.wicket/wicket-spring/1.5.16</bundle>
</feature>   
<feature name="wicket-ioc" version="1.5.16" description="Wicket ioc" resolver="(obr)">
    <feature version="1.5.16">wicket-core</feature>
    <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.wicket/wicket-ioc/1.5.16</bundle>
</feature>   
<feature name="wicket-core" version="1.5.16" description="Wicket core" resolver="(obr)">
    <feature version="1.5.16">wicket-request</feature>
    <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.wicket/wicket-core/1.5.16</bundle>
</feature> 

<feature name="wicket-request" version="1.5.16" description="Wicket request" resolver="(obr)">
<feature version="1.5.16">wicket-util</feature>
    <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.wicket/wicket-request/1.5.16</bundle>
</feature> 
<feature name="wicket-util" version="1.5.16" description="Wicket util" resolver="(obr)">
    <bundle start-level="30">mvn:org.apache.wicket/wicket-util/1.5.16</bundle>
</feature>
```

Including wicket jars in my WAR is not a desirable approach, how can I fix it?

*By the way, wicket-core.jar doesn't import org.apache.wicket.request in its manifest file, but I don't think that editing those manifests is the way to go*

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/request/Request
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)[:1.8.0_101]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createFilter(ServletContextHandler.java:1051)[50:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:104)[50:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[50:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:768)[50:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)[50:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)[50:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:222)[59:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.2.6]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[50:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:204)[59:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.end(HttpServiceStarted.java:1032)[58:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.end(HttpServiceProxy.java:422)[58:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.end(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:341)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:678)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:237)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:182)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:135)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:864)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:317)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:101)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver.deploy(WebObserver.java:213)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver$1.doStart(WebObserver.java:175)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.SimpleExtension.start(SimpleExtension.java:58)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.AbstractExtender$1.run(AbstractExtender.java:266)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.request.Request not found by org.apache.wicket.core [180]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_101]
... 38 more
2016-10-06 15:20:27,532 | WARN  | pool-4-thread-1  | AbstractLifeCycle                | 50 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.17.v20150415 | FAILED HttpServiceContext{httpContext=WebAppHttpContext{hub-web - 184}}:       
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/request/Request
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/request/Request
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)[:1.8.0_101]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createFilter(ServletContextHandler.java:1051)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[50:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:768)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:222)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[50:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:204)[59:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.end(HttpServiceStarted.java:1032)[58:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.end(HttpServiceProxy.java:422)[58:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.end(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:341)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:678)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:237)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:182)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:135)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:864)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:317)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:101)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver.deploy(WebObserver.java:213)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver$1.doStart(WebObserver.java:175)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.SimpleExtension.start(SimpleExtension.java:58)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.AbstractExtender$1.run(AbstractExtender.java:266)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.request.Request not found by org.apache.wicket.core [180]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_101]
... 38 more
```

Comment: Is that the full stack trace?  I'm wondering if wicket-request is missing a dependency and can't wire.. therefore wicket-core is unable to wire to wicket-request.  BTW-- I hate to be the "upgrade" comment.. but Wicket 6 and 7 are out.. 1.5 is really old. Are you sure you need 1.5.x?

Comment: Full stack added, I think my issue might be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432263/starting-wicket-web-application-with-osgi-http-service

but setting filter added there in my web.xml file did not help.

Comment: What version of SMX?  Is 1.5.x a requirement?  6, 7 are super stable and awesome

Comment: Wicket 7 uses spring 4.0 which is not supported by spring-dm, only spring 3.0

Comment: Gotcha..makes sense.. What rev of SMX?

Comment: I'm using 6.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution mentioned in [Starting Wicket web application with OSGi HTTP Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432263/starting-wicket-web-application-with-osgi-http-service) worked, but I had to upgrade wicket to 6.24.0. However new problem appeared - [Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean unable to find external properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903839/spring-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource-bean-unable-to-find-external-proper)